# Erro ao instalar symphony: fopen failed to open stream: Unable to find the socket transport "http"

Tags: php, symfony-2

Estou seguindo o [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-get-started-with-symfony-2-on-ubuntu-14-04) para a instalação do symfony, porém ocorre um erro ao executa-lo

```
  [GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException]
  Error creating resource: [message] fopen(https://get.symfony.com/symfony.version): failed to open stream: Unable to find
   the socket transport "http" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?
  [file] phar:///usr/local/bin/symfony/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Client/StreamHandler.php
  [line] 406
  [message] Undefined variable: http_response_header
  [file] phar:///usr/local/bin/symfony/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Client/StreamHandler.php
  [line] 407

  [GuzzleHttp\Ring\Exception\RingException]
  Error creating resource: [message] fopen(https://get.symfony.com/symfony.version): failed to open stream: Unable to find
   the socket transport "http" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?
  [file] phar:///usr/local/bin/symfony/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Client/StreamHandler.php
  [line] 406
  [message] Undefined variable: http_response_header
  [file] phar:///usr/local/bin/symfony/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Client/StreamHandler.php
  [line] 407
**
```

ja instalei o apt-get install php5-curl e mesmo assim, continua o problema

Answer (score 0):

Isto pode ser que o seu **SSL** não esteja ativado, para ativar com **PHP5** no Ubuntu va no *php.ini* e descomente (remova o `;` da frente do `extesion=`) a linha:

```
;extension=openssl.so
```

Deve ficar assim:

```
extension=openssl.so
```

Se for Windows descomente:

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Se for **PHP7.2** (windows e linux):

```
;extension=openssl
```

Outra solução que pode experimentar é ativar o CURL use o seguinte comando:

```
 sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

Se já tiver instalado e ainda não funcionar pode editar no php.ini e descomentar a linha (se for php5 com linux):

```
;extension=php_curl.dll
```

Se for windows:

```
;extension=curl.so
```

Se for **PHP7.2** (windows e linux):

```
;extension=curl
```

Comment: Realizei as configurações e agora mostra o seguinte erro:  
symfony new myproject
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_curl.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_curl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0